# Whether a certain sentence is correct or not

Tags: sentence-construction

I was on facebook, and I came across a status that went, **"When you suck at studies, and have tests starting the next day onward."**, alongside it was a picture that went with the caption.

I was wondering whether the caption he used is grammatically correct:

> When you suck at studies, and have tests starting the next day onward.

Comment: You have successfully used the bold formatting markup  **   Now try out the italic markup _ and the block quote symbol >  .  Note that while the bold and italic markup surround the text to be formatted, the block quote needs to be the first line character on a new line.  See the formatting sandbox for more options:  http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2923/formatting-sandbox-please-test-stuff-here?cb=1

Comment: What exactly troubles you? It's not really a "sentence" (just a dependent clause), but structurally it seems to me to be no different to *When you're stuck, and have no-one to turn to*. Which can easily be converted into a complete sentence by continuing with something like *...come to ELL for helpful advice.*

Comment: I'm guessing it was a ["meme" or "image macro"](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/image-macros), and not only is the grammar of such things unimportant to the author, it is often deliberately, even aggressively incorrect or at least non-standard, for humorous effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short version is (To quote FumbleFinger's comment above) "It's not really a "sentence" (just a dependent clause)". It cannot grammatically stand alone, but is an okay partial sentence.

That said, its a common construction on the modern internet to type like that as a caption, and the rest of the sentence is implied to be something like "...it feels like what is happening in this picture"

So if the picture posted was someone about to fall off a cliff, the sentence would be implied to be

> When you suck at studies, and have tests starting the next day onward, it feels like you are about to fall off a cliff.

Comment: A similar use as when they post a picture with the caption "That moment when ..."